# Replace words in a string using multidimensional array of contents

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, str-replace

I am using `str_replace` :

```
foreach( $languages as $lang ) {
    $html = str_replace( $lang['english'], $lang['german'], $html );
}
```

The `$languages` array contains :

```
$languages = array(array('english'=>'accessories','german'=>'xxxx'),array('english'=>'accessories table','german'=>'yyyyyyyy') );
```

Now the issue is that it outputs accessories as `xxxx` and `accessories table` as `xxxxx` table instead of outputting accessories table as `yyyyyyyy`

Comment: This is what I would expect it to do, after the str_replace changes it to `xxxx` its no longer what it was.

Comment: If you try to roll your own localization library you're going to have a *real* bad time. http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Well, sorting them might help

Comment: @Sammitch I don't see any reason for not trying.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat - some things are just not worth rebuilding.  I can see rolling your own template system, even MVC framework. But something like this takes a lot of language knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the "longest" matched term first.

by rearranging your `$languages` array, it should solve the problem

```
$languages = array(array('english'=>'accessories table','german'=>'yyyyyyyy'), array('english'=>'accessories','german'=>'xxxx'));
```

Comment: What if `$languages` has 1000 elements?

Comment: use custom `uksort` (by length descending) on the `$language` array

Comment: I think `ksort` accepts a flag of int, not a comparator.

Comment: sorry it's `uksort`

Comment: `uksort` is not a better option in the above context, because it sorts array by keys, and those keys are `0`, `1`, `2` in `$languages` and OP should use `$languages[$index]['english']` for sorting. You will need another sorting function.

Comment: ah, forgot about the nested array, `usort` should be sufficient

Comment: Don't worry, happens to all of us :)